# Union of all finite fields of order $p^i$, for some prime number $p$ is algebraically closed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime number. Consider for all $k,r\in\mathbb{N}_0$ with $k|r$ the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$. Define

$$ \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}:=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}_0}\mathbb{F}_{p^i}.$$

I want to show that $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. I already managed to show that $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is a field and that it is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$, but I can't seem to show that it is also algebraically closed.

I know that for every $i\in\mathbb{N}_0$, $\mathbb{F}_{p^i}$ is a decomposition field of the polynomial $X^{p^i}-X$. Which means this polynomial can be expressed as
$$X^{p^i}-X=\prod_{a\in\mathbb{F}_{p^i}}(X-a),$$

and I thought that this could help me prove that every irreducibel polynomial in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}[X]$ has degree $1$ but so far it hasn't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: An "innocent" question. What do you mean by the union here? For example, let $p=2$. Then $\Bbb{F}_4=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$, $\Bbb{F}_8=\Bbb{F}_2/(x^3+x+1)$, $\Bbb{F}_{16}=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^4+x+1)$, $\Bbb{F}_{32}=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5+x^2+1)$,
$\Bbb{F}_{64}=\Bbb{F}_2[x](x^6+x+1)$, $\Bbb{F}_{128}=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^7+x^3+1)$ etc. What does their union look like? Keep in mind that some of these have non-trivial intersections, and the injective embeddings of subfields are not unique.

Comment: [My attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/824137/11619) at answering that is to form a nested chain, when the (set theoretic) direct limit is simple to manage.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3967894/11619). Because I have no less than three applicable dupehammers, my vote would take immedate effect. So I will wait for a few minutes at least so that people can object.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That is indeed a duplicate, I guess it didn't pop up as a suggestion when creating my question.

Answer (score 1):

If $q(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{p^k}[x]$ is of degree $n$ and irreducible, $q$ has a non zero root in the rupture field $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}[x]/(q)$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{(p^k)^n}= \mathbb{F}_{p^{kn}}$.

By induction, you can prove that $q$ splits in one of the $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$. Which implies the desired result.